# Unable to compile when installing vmware clarity using ng add @clr/angular command

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Today I was trying to create project using vmware clarity. but for some reason it is throwing error. I am unable to compile the project. I think the command is installing version 2 which is not supporting the project.

below are the error and angular.json and package.json file.

Can I install particular version in vmware clarity

ERROR

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@clr/angular/fesm5/clr-angular.js 749:39-57
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@clr/angular/fesm5/clr-angular.js 2523:39-57
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@clr/angular/fesm5/clr-angular.js 5691:49-67
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@clr/angular/fesm5/clr-angular.js 13579:50-68
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "availability",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@clr/angular": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@clr/ui": "2.0.0",
    "@clr/icons": "2.0.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

ANGULAR.JSON

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "availability": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/availability",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css",
              "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
              "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "availability:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "availability:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "availability:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "availability-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "availability:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "availability:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "availability"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issues seem familiar for an Angular 8 upgrade. Maybe CLR has already upgraded to Angular 8 and you will have to do as well, or you will need to grab an older version of CLR that is still compatible with version 6 you're using.

CLR-angular version 2 (beta) indeed is updated for Angular 8. You can revert to version `1.1.3` or upgrade your project to Angular 8. :-)

`ng update` should do the trick, do your `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core` first with `ng update` and the rest should explain itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an old version of Angular, you'll have to install Clarity using a tag to get a compatible version.

Clarity v0.13 supports Angular 6, so you would have to run `ng add @clr/angular@0.13.11` to get that specific version setup for you.